# connected component labeling using stack

Tags: c

I just coded connected component labeling by recursion
But I want non recursive version by using stack and structure.

```
typedef struct _node{
int Xpos;
int Ypos;
int dir;    
}node;

node *stack[MAX];
node *push(node *t) {
stack[++top] = t;
return t;
}

node *pop() {
return stack[top--];
    }
```

Structure Component do have Xposition and Yposition and Direction.
ex) 
if(t->dir == 1)  {t->Xpos = ++t->Xpos, t->Ypos = --t->Ypos};
8-neighbor labeling
I really do need help!
//edit

// edit
here's what i made by recursion

```
#define MAP_SIZE 15
#define INILBCNT    10
int cnt = 1;
int input_map[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE] =
{ {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}
};



void PrintMap()
{
system("cls");

for (int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", input_map[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");   }  }

void glassFire(int mask_Y, int mask_X)
{

if (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] != 1)
    return;
else
    if (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] == 1)
    {
        input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] = cnt;            
        glassFire(mask_Y, mask_X + 1);
        glassFire(mask_Y + 1, mask_X);
        glassFire(mask_Y + 1, mask_X + 1);
        glassFire(mask_Y + 1, mask_X - 1);
        glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X + 1);
        glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X);
        glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X + 1);
        glassFire(mask_Y, mask_X - 1); }}

void Serching()
{
PrintMap();
for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; j++)
    {

        if (input_map[j][i] == 1)
        {
            cnt++;
            glassFire(j, i);}
      }
   }
}
```

This code just worked well.

Answer (score 2):

> This code just worked well.

No, this code has undefined behavior because you read/write in `input_map` with `mask_Y` and/or `mask_X` valuing -1 and/or 15 because of the recursive calls adding/removing 1 to `mask_Y` / `mask_X`

In

> ```
> void glassFire(int mask_Y, int mask_X)
> {
>   if (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] != 1)
>     return;
>   else
>     if (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] == 1)
>     {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

the first *if* is useless, but you have to check the indexes, can be :

```
void glassFire(int mask_Y, int mask_X)
{
   if ((mask_Y >= 0) && (mask_X >= 0) &&
       (mask_Y < MAP_SIZE) && (mask_X < MAP_SIZE) &&
       (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] == 1))
   {
        ...
   }
}
```

You call two times `glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X + 1);`, one must be replaced by `glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X - 1);` which is missing.

Rather than to do

> ```
>    glassFire(mask_Y, mask_X + 1);
>    glassFire(mask_Y + 1, mask_X);
>    glassFire(mask_Y + 1, mask_X + 1);
>    glassFire(mask_Y + 1, mask_X - 1);
>    glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X + 1);
>    glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X);
>    glassFire(mask_Y - 1, mask_X - 1); /*  modified */
>    glassFire(mask_Y, mask_X - 1); }}
> ```

you can use a loop ( that will help to manage the recursions by hand, changing less code ) :

```
    static const YX offset[] = {
      {0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,-1}, {-1,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1}, {0,-1}
    };

    for (int dir = 0; dir != 8; ++dir) 
      glassFire(mask_Y + offset[dir].y, mask_X + offset[dir].x);
```

with `typedef struct YX { int y; int x; } YX;`

---

To remove the recursive calls your structure containing a direction is not appropriate because a recursive call can do an other recursive call etc, you just need to save the indexes you will have to manage later.

Note fortunately the result does not depend on the order of the recursive calls.

A solution can be :

```
void glassFire(int mask_Y, int mask_X)
{
  YX * stack = NULL;
  size_t sz = 0;
  size_t deep = 0;

  for (;;) {
    if (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] == 1) /* need to check, can be false now */
    {
      input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] = cnt;

      static const YX offset[] = {
        {0,1},  {1,0},  {1,1}, {1,-1}, {-1,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1},  {0,-1}
      };

      /* up to 8 positions to save */
      if ((deep + 8) > sz) {
        sz += 8;
        stack = realloc(stack, sz * sizeof(YX));
      }

      for (int dir = 0; dir != 8; ++dir) {
        int ny = mask_Y + offset[dir].y;
        int nx = mask_X + offset[dir].x;

        if ((ny >= 0) && (nx >= 0) &&
            (ny < MAP_SIZE) && (nx < MAP_SIZE) &&
            (input_map[ny][nx] == 1))
        {
          stack[deep].y = ny;
          stack[deep].x = nx;
          deep += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    if (deep == 0)
      /* empty */
      break;

    deep -= 1;
    mask_Y = stack[deep].y;
    mask_X = stack[deep].x;
  }

  free(stack);
}
```

---

If I use that full program (I removed *INILBCN* which is useless) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAP_SIZE 15
int cnt = 1;
int input_map[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE] =
{ {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}
};

void PrintMap()
{
  for (int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; j++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", input_map[j][i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
}

typedef struct YX { int y; int x; } YX;

void glassFire(int mask_Y, int mask_X)
{
  YX * stack = NULL;
  size_t sz = 0;
  size_t deep = 0;

  for (;;) {
    if (input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] == 1)
    {
      input_map[mask_Y][mask_X] = cnt;

      static const YX offset[] = {
        {0,1},  {1,0},  {1,1}, {1,-1}, {-1,1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1},  {0,-1}
      };

      /* 8 positions to save */
      if ((deep + 8) > sz) {
        sz += 8;
        stack = realloc(stack, sz * sizeof(YX));
      }

      for (int dir = 0; dir != 8; ++dir) {
        int ny = mask_Y + offset[dir].y;
        int nx = mask_X + offset[dir].x;

        if ((ny >= 0) && (nx >= 0) &&
            (ny < MAP_SIZE) && (nx < MAP_SIZE) &&
            (input_map[ny][nx] == 1))
        {
          stack[deep].y = ny;
          stack[deep].x = nx;
          deep += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    if (deep == 0)
      /* empty */
      break;

    deep -= 1;
    mask_Y = stack[deep].y;
    mask_X = stack[deep].x;
  }

  free(stack);
}

void Serching() /* probably searching */
{
  PrintMap();

  for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (input_map[j][i] == 1)
        {
          cnt++;
          glassFire(j, i);}
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
  Serching();
  putchar('\n');
  PrintMap();
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 0 
0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 4 4 0 4 0 
0 2 0 2 2 0 2 0 4 4 4 0 0 4 0 
0 2 0 0 2 0 2 0 4 0 0 0 0 4 0 
0 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 4 0 0 5 0 4 0 
0 0 0 2 2 0 2 0 4 0 5 5 0 4 0 
0 3 0 2 2 0 2 0 4 0 5 0 0 4 0 
0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 5 0 0 4 0 
0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 0 0 4 0 
0 3 3 3 3 3 0 4 0 0 5 5 0 4 0 
0 0 0 0 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 0 0 4 0 
0 3 3 3 0 3 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 
0 3 0 0 0 3 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 
0 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0
```

I let `cnt` and `input_map` global, but they can be local into *Serching* and given in parameters to *glassFire*. The less there are global variables the better it is.

Note my code produces the same result as your (modulo the corrections), but I cannot know if your code was right because I do not know what it really has to do ;-)